# fontspec Color option overrides subsection number color

Tags: fontspec

How do I achieve this:
[image: desired output]

while I get this:
[image: my output]

To be specific, how do I make subsection number green color while text color is white by default.

I am using LuaLaTeX for compilation and Chirp font as the font of my choice.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{lblack}{RGB}{29,26,45}
\definecolor{gblack}{RGB}{33,31,50}
\definecolor{bgreen}{HTML}{2AB17E}
\pagecolor{lblack}
\setmainfont[Color=white, BoldFont={Chirp Bold}]{Chirp Regular}
\setsansfont[Color=white,BoldFont={Chirp Bold}]{Chirp Regular}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
                    help lines/.append style={line width=0.5pt,
                                              color=gblack}]
  \draw[help lines] (current page.south west) grid[step=0.25]
                    (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}.}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.25em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11}{15}\bfseries\color{bgreen}}{\thesubsection}{0.25em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Vocabulaire usuel des suites}
\subsection{Sens de variation d'une suite}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to change to another font where the fontspec color is not set (or set to green). fontspec colors always win.

Comment: I actually wanted text color to be white by default since the background is dark

Comment: sure, but then you can't use \color{green} to make it green.  A white font is always white.

Comment: Is there a way to make white by default other then setting `Color=white`